# How can i exclude .less files from publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, less, publish

I want to get only compiled css files in my output folder after publish. 
I tried to set "None" in file properties. It excludes file from publish, but WebEssentials can not compile it yet.

I thought it is a simple task to exclude *.less from publish folder (i choose File System Publish).

Are there any ideas? Maybe there is any way to configure publish xml? Or configure .project file?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ExcludeFilesFromDeployment property of the publish profile xml. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment).

Comment: Great! Thanks. Works as it should.